# Getting error 'explode input must be a string' on using jq for case conversion

Tags: json, jq

Looking to change all the values of name to Lower Case.

I am currently running

```
map( .[].data_node.name |= ascii_downcase)
```

and receive `jq: error (at data3.json:538): explode input must be a string` error.

Sample input:

```
[  
   {  
      "data_node":{  
         "name":"FRODO BAGGINS",
         "race":"hobbit",
         "existence":"middle earth"
      },
      "parent":"bilbo baggins"
   },
   {  
      "data_node":{  
         "name":"SAMWISE GAMJEE",
         "race":"hobbit",
         "existence":"middle earth"
      },
      "parent":"gamjee lord"
   },
   {  
         "data_node":{  
             "name":null,
             "race":"hobbit",
             "existence":"middle earth"
         },
         "parent":"bilbo baggins"
       }
    ]
```

Sample output:

```
[  
   {  
      "data_node":{  
         "name":"frodo baggins",
         "race":"hobbit",
         "existence":"middle earth"
      },
      "parent":"bilbo baggins"
   },
   {  
      "data_node":{  
         "name":"samwise gamjee",
         "race":"hobbit",
         "existence":"middle earth"
      },
      "parent":"gamjee lord"
   },
   {  
      "data_node":{  
         "name": null,
         "race":"hobbit",
         "existence":"middle earth"
      },
      "parent":"bilbo baggins"
   }
]
```

What's wrong with my current line of code and what's the solution to doing this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `if` condition to do the case conversion only *if* the `name` field is not `null` as

```
map( if (.data_node.name != null) then .data_node.name |= ascii_downcase else . end )
```

As far as the error you are seeing, I'd assume that the case conversion we apply does not apply to the `null` datatype in `jq` and only for string types.

To run it on the command-line directly without running as a script

```
jq 'map( if (.data_node.name != null) then .data_node.name |= ascii_downcase else . end )' < data3.json
```

[jqplay-URL](https://jqplay.org/s/Ms1RjbKlQe)

Comment: solution works. thank you! just out of curiosity though, ive been running my solutions with -s in the terminal as a script, how come i had to remove -s to run your solution?

Comment: `-s` takes all the inputs and adds them to an array. To work with this code, you'd need to explode that array: `jq -s '.[] | map(...)' file` versus `jq 'map(...)' file`

Answer (score 3):

More briefly and more robustly:

```
map(.data_node.name |= if type == "string" then ascii_downcase else . end)
```

Or still more briefly:

```
map(.data_node.name |= ascii_downcase? // .)
```

(These assume that jq is invoked without the -s option.)