# Case-insensitive search of an object with jq

Tags: json, select, jq, case-insensitive

When retrieving an object from an array with `jq` in a JSON file like this

```
[
  {
    "field1": "Object1_Value1",
    "field2": "Object1_Value2",
    "field3": "Object1_Value3"
  },
  {
    "field1": "Object2_Value1",
    "field2": "Object2_Value2",
    "field3": "Object2_Value3"
  }
]
```

that matches a given string, `.field1` may include capital letters:

```
jq --raw-output '.[] | select(.field1 == "object1_value1") | .field2, .field3' filename
```

How can `ascii_downcase` be used here to match the string in lower case?

Comment: Do you mean `select(.field1 | ascii_downcase == "searched value in lower case")`?

Comment: @pmf this raises the error `jq: error (at filename:1020852): explode input must be a string`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Here's a [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WA698o9bd2B) using your updated values.

Comment: Looks that it has to do with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50943201/4179803

Comment: But don't know how to use it in a `select` search...

Comment: @pmf the error is raised when an object lacks the searched field, like in this [modified demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KpOBoIsCIbE), and that is the case in the real JSON file, as I have checked now.

Comment: That's a completely different issue. Use `try` (or `?`) as in `select(try .field1 | …`.

Comment: That works, even if it makes the search more time consuming (140k objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your given input, the following should work, no?

```
.[] | select(.field1 | ascii_downcase == "object1_value1") | .field1, .field3
```

To suppress errors for non-existing fields, append `?`:

```
.[] | select(.field1 | ascii_downcase? == "object1_value1") | .field1, .field3
```

You can also try filtering on the presence of the field first:

```
.[] | select(has("field1")) | select(.field1 | ascii_downcase == "object1_value1") | .field1, .field3
```

Output:

```
Object1_Value1
Object1_Value3
```

Comment: Only problem is that this triples the search time, with respect to a coherent JSON file.

Comment: @nightcod3r the question didn't specify any runtime constraints. Is it a problem? What processing times are we talking about?

Comment: You're right, but in this case it would help, since it goes from interactive to non-interactive, it's a rather big database.

Comment: It's not the check, but the down case conversion what slows down the search, so the solution given by @pmf and summarized by you is correct.

Comment: @nightcod3r you can try first matching the exact case and then the downcased version: `select((.field1 == "object1_value1") or (.field1 | ascii_downcase? == "object1_value1"))`. I'm not sure if this will improve your runtime or whether jq does short circuit evaluation of boolean expressions.